# how to get SSID and BSSID OF Hotspot of my device programmatically

Tags: android

I want to get my own device `Wi-Fi SSID` and `BSSID name`.
How can I get this?
I tried this

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
System.out.println("BSSID"+wifiConfiguration.BSSID);
```

But this code gives the BSSID of the device to which i currently connected but i wants to get my own device `BSSID` `ssid` through code??
Please help Me.

Comment: you should edit your question so that it's clear you are asking about the hotspot information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the device's hotspot SSID or BSSID, use something like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
Method[] methods = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m: methods) {           
    if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
        WifiConfiguration config = (WifiConfiguration)m.invoke(wifimanager);
        String ssid = config.SSID;
        String bssid = config.BSSID;
    }
}
```

---

You can use [`WifiManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) and [`WifiInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.htm) for the Wifi info the device connected to, like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid  = info.getSSID();
String bssid = info.getBSSID();
```

You would need the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Note**: since Android 8.0, you would also need location permissions (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) to access the SSID or BSSID because of [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/e42dd31b3f656f33be99fd37f26e07557d163b54#diff-87dc47bf75c6bbb0d746d9671c2aedf6), also, I think you need to have the device's location settings turned on for this to work even if you have the location permissions.

Comment: Thank You :) Your First  Code Works Well :)

Comment: Its Working Fine For SSID But for BSSID its giving null  value

Comment: its not working on Android10+ as 'android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration' is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and then use this method

```
public static String getBSSID(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if(mNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
        final WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final WifiInfo mWifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if(mWifiInfo != null) {
            return mWifiInfo.getBSSID();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey Bro your Code gives me the name of router which i currently connected but i wants to get my device wifi name which we can see in settings>hotspotSettings but i want to do this with code :(

Comment: Yeah I have Checked but the answer is same :(

Comment: I think @Logic means the current device's hotspot's info.